# Received contradictory error message while using float function

Tags: matlab

I'm attempting to convert a column of integers into a column of floats with the float function. When I run the following command:

```
hourlyuncorrectedcount = float(hourlyuncorrectedcount);
```

It returns the errror:

```
The input argument to float was not a supported type. The only 
recognized input character vectors are 'single' and 'double'. The input 
type was 'double'.
```

Which as far as I can tell doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Can you add the code to how you obtained `hourlyuncorrectedcount`?

Comment: [`float`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/float.html) is a [MuPad](https://www.mathworks.com/discovery/mupad.html) function from the Symbolic Math Toolbox. Use [`double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html) or [`single`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/single.html)

Comment: If you just want more values after your decimal, use format long.

Comment: How does "*The only 
recognized input character vectors are 'single' and 'double'.*" not make any sense?

Comment: @Flynn what is unclear about "a column of integers?" Integers don't have decimals.

Comment: What was unclear was the next line: "input type was 'double'. " Is that saying I'm putting in a double and that's wrong? Even though the sentence before says that a double is valid?

Comment: It does not say a double is valid.

Comment: It clearly does in the second sentence, "The only recognized input character vectors are 'single' and 'double'."

Comment: I guess it "clearly" does if you skip over the "input *character* vectors" portion. A `double` is not a character vector.

Answer (score 3):

[`float`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/float.html) is a [MuPAD](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad-1.html) function and is not compatible with numeric arrays. MuPAD is part of the [Symbolic Math Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/index.html) and provides similar functionality to things like [Jupyter Notebooks](https://jupyter.org/) and MATLAB's [Live Scripts](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/live-scripts.html); the latter was introduced into the base install of MATLAB R2016a and supersedes MuPAD.

MuPAD is separate from the general MATLAB IDE, and `float` only accepts MuPAD objects, not numeric arrays. The error message could be much clearer but it does explicitly state that the input needs to be a *character* vector, which makes sense in the context of MuPAD but not with "regular" MATLAB.

To cast an integer array to a float, use [`double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html) or [`single`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/single.html).

See also: [MATLAB's Numeric Types](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/numeric-types.html)

Answer (score -3):

You can't use float. I'm assuming you have double precision, and you can change that to single. But those are your options.

NOTE MuPAD are not recommended:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/float.html

Read here:
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/286934
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/floating-point-numbers.html